# Need to filter a string and it's value from ansible output

Tags: ansible

Am running a task in ansible playbook and output of that task is a Json .From that output I need to find mropt and it's value and register that to a separate variable

```
    - debug:
         msg: " {{ mydata}}"
      register: output
```

Output :

"msg": " [{u'Rex': {u'2012': {u'Applied': u'20120118'}}, u'block': {u'mropt': u'yes'}}]"

I tried the below

```
   - set_fact:
       is_data: "Applicable"
     when: "'mropt' in mydata"
```

Above command did not work and so tried to do the debug to see if I get the result

```
- debug: 
        msg: "is data available {{ output}}"
      when: "'mropt' in output"
      with_items: output.results
```

Expected result would be :

is_data should be set to applicable when 'mropt' value is Yes and is_data should be set to No when 'mropt' key is not available. (mropt key is not available in output when the value is set to no)

Answer (score 0):

Your first `when` condition fails because, based on the output you've shown in your question, `mropt` is not `in mydata`.  `mydata` is a list of dictionaries containing a single dictionary, and `mropt` is a key in that dictionary.  A test like the following would work:

```
- set_fact:
    is_data: "Applicable"
  when: "'mropt' in mydata.0.block"
```

This assumes, of course, that you're only ever interested in the first item in the `mydata` list.

In your second example, you're using a variable `output` that you haven't defined anywhere, so it's impossible to tell if that would work or not.

Comment: I get the below error when I tried

{
    "msg": "The conditional check ''mropt' in mydata.0.block' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('mropt' in mydata.0.block): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if 'mropt' in mydata.0.block %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable\n\n,
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}

Comment: It sounds like in that case something (either `mydata`, or `mydata.0` or `mydata.0.block`) was undefined. If you can show the `debug` output for the situation that generated the error it would be easier to diagnose.